# Calculating Distance Between Two Give Points using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.22 and having two given Points as

```
var pt1 = new Point(-106.61, 35.1107, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 }));
var pt2 = new Point(-108.61, 35.1107, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 }));
```

can you please let me know how I can calculate the distance from `pt1` to `pt2`?

```
var map;
    require([
             "esri/map",
             "esri/geometry/Point",
             "esri/SpatialReference",
             "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils",
             "dojo/domReady!"
 ], function(Map, Point, SpatialReference, webMercatorUtils) {

 map = new Map("map", {
       basemap: "topo",
       center: [-106.61, 35.1107],
       zoom: 8
 });
 var geometryService = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("https://utility.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

 var pt1 = new Point(-106.61, 35.1107, new SpatialReference({wkid: 4326 }));
 var pt2 = new Point(-108.61, 35.1107, new SpatialReference({wkid: 4326 }));

});
```

Comment: Hi Shiko but this post is not even close to what you have mentioned!

Comment: Hi Mona, it is mentioned in the quesiton and answer the function used to get the distance `esri.geometry.getLength(p1, p2)`

Comment: but it just return 2! what is it? a Meter? Kilomrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked the coordinates system you were using in the example, you are using WGS84 which is a geographic but the`getLength` in ArcGIS works on projected, so you need to convert the coordinates first using `geographicToWebMercator`.

```
 var pt1 = new Point(-106.61, 35.1107, new SpatialReference({wkid: 4326 }));
 var pt2 = new Point(-108.61, 35.1107, new SpatialReference({wkid: 4326 }));
 var pt1_web = webMercatorUtils.geographicToWebMercator(pt1);
 var pt2_web = webMercatorUtils.geographicToWebMercator(pt2);
 var meter_value = esri.geometry.getLength(pt1_web,pt2_web);
 var km_value = meter_value/1000;
```

**References:**
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-support-webMercatorUtils.html#geographicToWebMercator 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.geometry.mathutils.html#getlength